# How to get data from selected item in ListBox and display to checkedBoxList?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, forms

[image]I am working on Windows Form Application. On the Form, i have placed one ListBox and on another tab there is CheckBoxList. I have populated my ListBox with my SQL Datasource. Now, i want to display the list items of each selected item in ListBox and show it to CheckBoxList.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListBox.SelectedValueChanged event (or SelectedIndexChanged). Then use the ListBox.SelectedValue property to filter the CheckBoxList Items.

The method for filtering the CheckBoxList depends on how the items are bound. If they are from a database, then I would use SQL to filter the list. (inside the SelectedValueChanged event)

If you post the code that you have tried, I can try to walk you through it.

**Edit:** Your select statement is "Select * from Electronics", so it looks like you are storing each category in it's own table. If this is the case, you could do something like this:

```
string query = null;
switch (listBoxCat.SelectedValue) {
    case "Electronics":
        query = "SELECT * FROM Electronics";
        break;
    case "Woman":
        query = "SELECT * FROM Woman";
        break;
    //case etc, etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

namespace JustBuyIt
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

```
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tabControl1.SelectedIndex + 1;
    }


    private void listBoxCat_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //SQL Data Source
        string datasource = "Data Source=LENOVO-NQ;Initial Catalog=JustBuy;Integrated Security=True";


        //Query
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Electronics";

        //ConnectionString
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(datasource);

        //SQL Command
        SqlCommand myComm = new SqlCommand(query, myConn);
        //Data Reader
        SqlDataReader myDataReader;
        try
        {
            myConn.Open();
            myDataReader = myComm.ExecuteReader();

            while (myDataReader.Read())
            {
                string temp = myDataReader.GetString(1);
                checkedListBox1.Items.Add(temp);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            MessageBox.Show("Nothing to show!");
        }


    }
```